# Android timer that counts when app is closed

Tags: android

I have an activity in which I want to track the time elapsed between two actions(for example startAction and endAction). I've used the following code to implement a timer that increments every 500 ms after the user presses the button for startAction:

```
TextView dayTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDayTimer);
long startTime;
class DayTimer extends TimerTask {

             @Override
             public void run() {
                 BBCAndroid.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  
                     public void run() {
                        long millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
                        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
                        int minutes = seconds / 60;
                        seconds     = seconds % 60;

                        dayTimer.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
                     }
                 });
             }
        };


      startDayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                            startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        timer.schedule(new DayTimer(),  0,500);
                        LoginResult.DayState = 1;
                        startDayButton.setEnabled(false);
                        endDayButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Now my problem is that, if I exit the application the timer stops. How can I make it run even when the user is out of the app?
In summary, I need a timer that counts even if the app is closed.

Comment: You could save a start timestamp and use it with the current timestamp to calculate the time passed. Like this, even if the user closes the app completely, the timer will work again when reopened.

Comment: f you want your app to run even when it isn't running, you'll have to use a Service which run in background and is never closed by the system.
Or, when the application is about to be closed, you could memorize the date and time value and see the difference when your app is launched again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and it will be up and running even if your application is closed.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or create a thread in which your timer runs. This wouldn't destroy your timer when you app is closed.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved your problem using the life cycle.

If the application is not destroyed you can count time by applying your code to the onPause or onStop.

But you have to advertise the user when he is going to destroy the app.

This was my solution to continue receiving messages with my app running in the foreground and to avoid excessive power consumption.

Read about the lifeCycle here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

I hope this can be useful.